# ¿Cómo contar en R el número de valores distintos de una columna de un fichero excel?

Tags: r

Tengo la columna "Numero de identificacion de vehiculo"  y las fechas de todos los días de un mes.
Cada vehículo lleva un código identificador, por tanto quisiera contar cuántos codigos distintos hay en cada día del mes.
Para separar los días, utilizo el comando `subset()` , pero no se como realizar el recuento de codigos diferentes.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo de tus datos?

Answer (score 1):

hSi x es tu vector, entonces:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,3,4)
unique(x)
```

Si es un data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,3,4))
unique(df$a)
```

Si tus datos están agrupados por días (te recomiendo que cuando preguntes pongas tu código o bien un ejemplo de tus datos) puedes agruparlos y contar etiquetas diferentes en cada:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(días = c("lunes", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles"),
                 vehículo = c("a", "a", "b", "c"))
df %>% group_by(días) %>% count(vehículo)
```